# Подмена ip адреса в udp пакете

Tags: linux, сокет, udp

Через сырые сокеты я создал udp пакет с измененным айпи адресом отправителя. Но при попытке отправить его на другой сервер приходит пакет с настоящим айпи адресом. Я пробовал отправить пакет на  локалку и приходит пакет с измененным айпи адресом. Также с hping3. В чем может быть проблема? Связано ли это с тем, что устройство с которого отправлен пакет подключено не на прямую к интернету, а через роутер? Спрашивал у провайдера, сказали не блокируют такое. ОС Linux

Comment: Вангую на роутере NAT

Comment: вот так обычный домашний NAT остановил большую ддос атаку в будущем.